# how can i use JavaScript to change the background color of individual letters in html text

Tags: javascript, html, background-color

I am currently making a typing game. I have two variables; the first is the text that the user needs to type, and the second is the text the user has to is currently typing.

I have been able to make it so when the program can detect if the two variables are equal. But also when the text so far is equal to the text they need to write. For example if you need to type "test" and you've only typed "te" it will still be considered correct. Because you haven't made any mistakes so far.

Anyway, I want the individual letters / characters to be highlighted when its either correct or incorrect. Because at the moment it will only highlight the entire word.

```js
// Variables
let textBox = document.getElementsByClassName("text-box")[0];
let textShownInWebPage = document.getElementsByClassName("text-to-type")[0];
let typedValue;
let typedValueArray;
let displayText = "Just some sample text."
let characterArray = displayText.split("");
let i;

const run = () => {
    typedValue = textBox.value;

    let isCorrect = true;

    for (i = 0; i < typedValue.length; i++) {
      if (typedValue[i] !== displayText[i]) {
        isCorrect = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (isCorrect) {
      console.log("correct");
      textShownInWebPage.style.backgroundColor = "#f0290e";
    } else {
      console.log("incorrect");
      textShownInWebPage.style.backgroundColor = "#eb2323";
```

```html
<div><span class="text-to-type">Just some sample text.</span></div>
<textarea class="text-box" rows="8" cols="55" oninput="run()"></textarea>

<!-- The line below is for JavaScript -->
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

I have tried using this line of code but it only creates error messages and I'm unsure why.

```
textShownInWebPage[i].style.backgroundColor = "#eb2323";
```

Comment: Having converted your posted code into a snippet, there's an error reported in the console: `SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement`. Could you please correct the JavaScript (we're not supposed to do it for you, in case that solves the problem or invalidates existing answers).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `oninput` in your code.
you can call your matching function in oninput like this `<input type="text" oninput="myFunction()">`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple first attempt:
As long as there have not been any errors in the typed text, that portion will be shown with a green background in the div above. Unfortunately, once an error is encountered, the hilighting will be removed for the whole text.

```js
const [txt,box]=[".text-to-type",".text-box"].map(sel=>document.querySelector(sel));
function run(){
 txt.innerHTML=txt.textContent.replace(box.value,"<span class=\"ok\">$&</span>");
}
```

```css
.ok {background-color: green }
```

```html
<div><span class="text-to-type">Just some sample text.</span></div>
<textarea class="text-box" rows="8" cols="55" oninput="run()"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code. When correct letters entered letters are colored green. Added an alert and a remove letter when wrong. When you delete letters you only keep what in textarea equivalent colored.

```js
let textBox = document.getElementsByClassName("text-box")[0];
let textShownInWebPage = document.getElementsByClassName("text-to-type")[0];
let displayText = "another word"


for(let i=0;i<displayText.length;i++){
    let span = document.createElement("span")
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(displayText[i])
    span.appendChild(textNode)
    textShownInWebPage.appendChild(span)
}


const run = () => {
    let typedValue = textBox.value;
    let counter = 0
    let letterSpan = document.getElementsByTagName("span")
    for(i=1; i<=typedValue.length;i++){
        if(typedValue[i-1] == displayText[i-1]){
            console.log(typeof(typedValue[i-1]),typeof(displayText[i-1]))
            counter++
            letterSpan[i-1].style.backgroundColor = "green" 
            if(counter==displayText.length){
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    alert('you won')
                    typedValue="";
                    textShownInWebPage.innerHTML = ''
                    textBox.value = ""
                },500)
                return
            }
        }

        if(typedValue[i-1] != displayText[i-1]){
            alert('wrong letter , will be removed')
            inTextArea = textBox.value
            console.log(inTextArea)
            inTextArea = inTextArea.slice(0,-1)
            typedValue = inTextArea
            setTimeout(()=>{
                textBox.value = inTextArea},400)
            return
        }
    }
    for(i=typedValue.length;i<displayText.length;i++){
        if(typedValue[i-1] === displayText[i-1]){
            counter++
            letterSpan[i].style.backgroundColor = "transparent" 
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="text-to-type"></div> 
<textarea class="text-box" rows="8" cols="55" oninput="run()"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are serious issues of logic in your code.
Any variables that are set outside of a function, can become inaccessible outside of it.

here's the correct and working Javascript:

```
// Variables
let textBox ;
let textShownInWebPage;
let typedValue;
let typedValueArray;
let i;

var coloring = function(isCorrect){
    var textShownInWebPage = document.getElementsByClassName("text-to-type")[0];
    if (isCorrect) {
        console.log("correct");
        textShownInWebPage.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else {
        console.log("incorrect");
        textShownInWebPage.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

const run = () => {

    let displayText = "Just some sample text.";
    let characterArray = displayText.split("");
    
    let textBox = document.getElementsByClassName("text-box")[0];
    let typedValue = textBox.value;
    let isCorrect = true;

    for (i = 0; i < typedValue.length; i++) {
        if (typedValue[i] !== displayText[i]) {
            isCorrect = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    coloring(isCorrect);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Dynamic Code Snippet of your code

```js
  let textToType = document.getElementById("text-to-type");
  let textBox = document.getElementsByClassName("text-box")[0];
  let typedValue;
  let displayText = "Just some sample text."; // This text will add to text-to-type div 
  let getTextSpan = textToType.getElementsByTagName("span");

  window.onload = () => {
    for (var i in displayText) {
      const spanTag = document.createElement("span");
      const textNode = document.createTextNode(displayText[i]);
      spanTag.appendChild(textNode);
      textToType.appendChild(spanTag);
    }
  };

  const run = () => {
    typedValue = textBox.value;

    let isCorrect = true;

    for (let i in displayText) {
    // This nested loop will prevent red colour to show on the text that isn't  typed yet
      for (let j in typedValue) {
        if (typedValue.length <= displayText.length) {
          if (typedValue[j] !== displayText[j]) {
            getTextSpan[j].style.color = "red";
          }
        }
      }

      if (typedValue[i] === displayText[i]) {
        getTextSpan[i].style.color = "blue";
      } else {
      // black color for those chars that didn't typed yet
        getTextSpan[i].style.color = "black";
      }
    }
  };
```

```html
<body>

<!-- The Text will automatically add by javascript varaible textToType -->

<div id="text-to-type"></div> 
<textarea class="text-box" rows="8" cols="55" oninput="run()"></textarea>

</body>
```